# jQuery UI Resizable seems not to work with CSS Grid Layout

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-grid, jquery-ui-resizable

It looks like that jQuery UI Resizable seems not to work with CSS Grid Layout.
When resizing of an element starts, it jumps to the right adding the offset of the CSS grid.

```js
$('#resize').resizable();
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  position: relative;
}

.grid_cell {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
}

#resize {
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="grid">
  <div class='grid_cell'>
    grid cell
  </div>
  <div class="grid_cell">
    grid cell
  </div>
  <div id="resize">
    resize me!
  </div>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Bensky/91bgbfxg/11/

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve?: https://jsfiddle.net/svuu51y6/

Comment: no, the resize-div covers currently the second div. The user wants to resize it to cover also the first div. Like in a calendar, where a blocker is set on Tuesday and should be extended to Monday by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Hope below solution helps:

[JS fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ax1o4tg5/)

```js
$('#resize').resizable();
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  position: relative;
}
.grid_cell {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
}

#resize {
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  grid-column-start:1;
  grid-column-end: 3
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class='grid_cell'>
    grid cell
  </div>
  <div class="grid_cell">
    grid cell
  </div>
  <div id="resize">
    resize me!
  </div>
</div>
```